# How to adjust the data in Django's WSGIRequest requests to make it also visible in the views?

Tags: cryptography, django-middleware, django-wsgi, django-request

"I send an encrypted HTTP POST request, which is correctly received by the middleware on the Django server. The URL is successfully decrypted. However, I am facing difficulties in integrating the decrypted new data into the request so that it is readable in the views.

middleware.py

```py
class DecryptMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        path = request.path
        if path.startswith('/'):
            path = path[1:]

        f = Fernet(settings.ENCRYPTION_KEY)
        decrypted_path = f.decrypt(path.encode()).decode()
        elements = decrypted_path.split('/')
        element = f"/{elements[0]}/"
        data = elements[1]

        jsondata = json.loads(unquote(data))

        query_dict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
        for key, value in jsondata.items():
            query_dict.update({key: value})

        request.POST = query_dict
        request.method = 'POST'
        request.path = element
        request.path_info = element
        request.content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        request.META['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST'
        request.META['PATH_INFO'] = element
        request.META['QUERY_STRING'] = data
        request.META['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        request.META['CONTENT_LENGTH'] = str(len(request.body))

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

views.py

```py
class CreateUserView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        print("success")
        serializer = UserSerializer()
        print(f"request.POST:{request. POST}")
        print(f"request.data:{request. Data}")
        if serializer.create(data=request.data) == False :
            return Response({ "info" : " identifiant error" }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) 
        return Response({ }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Console OUTPUT:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 01, 2023 - 19:13:42
Django version 4.2.7, using settings 'APP.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

data:%7B%22username%22%3A%20%22XXXXXX%22%2C%20%22password%22%3A%20%22XXXXXX%22%2C%20%22email%22%3A%20%22XXXXXX%40XXXXXX.XXX%22%2C%20%22message%22%3A%20%22C%27XXXXXX
%20un%20XXXXXX%20de%20XXXXXX%22%7D
<QueryDict: {'username': ['XXXXXX'], 'password': ['XXXXXX'], 'email': ['xxxx.@xxx.xxx'], 'message': ["XXXXXX "]}>
success
request. POST:<QueryDict: {}>
request.data:<QueryDict: {}>
Bad Request: /create_user/
[01/Nov/2023 19:13:46] "POST /gAAAAABlQpVagCQkTohUKtiMXDBFDsx6p0Q06ytFfnQ0maeHHPpgsCFMpQ-zD_XVclellvc8JsWGqnACtlyYjPWRg__rwMmW2qJqmVMQFzn047OYb1B4ntyOkXYSjpv1B3frXNOdqXkPeuK7tZePI7rAdpWUPK-XUvNWHAxpiAyPWpWSoJt86vUMoDbCWC7zMUKyfOdoG6WV_yc2vMsRangold39FkzvFPBz2VXze87C6dw6byi1lYmAueXqEoYpe148LOe9Nm_EyEEYe52pH2rYnRbzOyRcb4n3qMuwporYF8EHeWBfVraPP1Mtd9R5syNpGeoiUf4Pyi6_sZQk--qiMJmsjp73HjD2SkaQkwg1jOzHiCO1gyc= HTTP/1.1" 400 29
```

I want to have this on views page :

```
request. POST:<QueryDict: {'username': ['value'], 'password': ['value'], 'email': ['value'], 'message': ['value']}>
request.data:<QueryDict: {'username': ['value'], 'password': ['value'], 'email': ['value'], 'message': ['value']}>
```